# Regex not working normally in python

Tags: python, regex

I have this pattern: `"(\?(.+?))\b"`.
In python, what should happen, is `findall` should return `("?var", "var")` if i run it on the string: `"some text ?var etc"`.

It works normally elsewhere, [here's a regexr for proof.](http://regexr.com/3arel)

In python, re's `findall` returns an empty list. Why is that?

Comment: I believe the [`re` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) starts off by explaining how to solve your problem.

Comment: @user2357112 I feel pretty stupid sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using raw string notation:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(\?(.+?))\b', 'some text ?var etc')
[('?var', 'var')]
```

Comment: Yours works, but why does `re.findall("(#{(.+?)})", "example #{findme}")` work without raw string notation?

Comment: Because there are no escape sequences.